# Why I am not able to enter Arabic text when editing a table in Informix14.10 having its DB_LOCALE=ar_ae.UTF8?

Tags: odbc, arabic, informix

I have an IBM Informix 14.10 database running on redhat8.
I created a database after setting the DB_LOCALE=ar_ae.UTF8.
The language of the database is as follows:

`select tabname, tabid, site from systables where tabid in(90,91)`

`tabname   GL_COLLATE  site     ar_AE.57372`

`tabname   GL_CTYPE site     ar_AE.57372`

Then create a table called tcustomers.
Then created an ODBC32 on Windows10 and connected to the database.
When editing fields on this table, I can type just **English text** and **neither Arabic nor French text are accepted**.  It is always giving an error: **An illegal character has been found in the statement**

On Windows 10 side I have IBM Informix-CSDK 4.10 installed

I set the **Client_Locale to ar_AE_UTF8**,  using the **setnet32** but it did not work too.

**My aim is to be able to type Arabic and English text into fields inside the database**.
Could someone help me find a solution?